# Google sheets - auto fill columns with formula for iterating column and specific cell ex:(B#*A1)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

As my title says, I'm trying to figure out a way to auto fill a column of cells with a formula that simply multiplies the value in iterating cells with a static value in a single other cell. So for example: column C-10 would be the product of B10xA1, Then C11 would be the product of B11xA1. Currently when I copy paste the formula into C column cells, it correctly adjusts the first parameter of the formula to iterate with corresponding cell, B10,B11,B12... but the second part of the formula does not stay static on cell A1, and begins to iterate as well, so the problem is that the cells copy and paste to: B10xA1, B11xA2, B12xA3, what I need is A1 to always be a static parameter multiplied by the dynamic parameter of the B cells. Is there a way to auto fill the C column to follow that formula pattern?

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(B10:B50 * A1)
```

if you want to play with dragging use:

```
=B10*A$1
```